# turning on or off a gpio pin

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os

Is there someone that knows how to simply turn on or off a gpio pin? I don't understand why rpi have to make it so hard. I hope someone gives me an answer, ask me if you don't understand the question. I have tried for a long time to find info online and ended up on this page.

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: i'm new and don't understand much but i think in python.

Comment: There are about 20 different ways in multiple languages. Try some research. Start at raspberrypi.com which has extensive documentation or read MagPi.

Comment: if what you want to do is simple enough, use a shell script https://simonprickett.dev/controlling-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-from-bash-scripts-traffic-lights/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of turning GPIO pin 23 on/off using the RPi.GPIO library:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

gpioPin = 23

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(gpioPin, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    print('on')
    GPIO.output(gpioPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print('off')
    GPIO.output(gpioPin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
```

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin16_gpio23